# how to fix bad request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use b crypt in the back end to compare the encrypted password and i keep getting invalid password and even so still lets me in here is my code for the back end...

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
const {
userName = req.body.userName,
password = req.body.password,
} = req.query;

connection.query(
SELECT_USER_QUERY + ' WHERE username = ? ',
[userName],
function (error, results, fields) {
  if (error) throw error;
  else {
    if (results.length > 0) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password, function (err, result) {
        if (result) {
          return res.send({ message: 'Login Successful' });
        } else {
          return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Invalid Password' });
        }
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'Invalid userName' });
    }
  }
}
);
});
```

my query looks like this...

```
const SELECT_USER_QUERY = 'SELECT id, firstName, lastName, userName,' +
' password, email FROM users';
```

and  here is where I call it...

```
handleLogIn = () => {
const { userName } = this.state.user;
const { users } = this.state;

postFetch(`/users/login`, {
  id: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id,
  firstName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName)
    .firstName,
  lastName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).lastName,
  userName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).userName,
  password: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).password,
  email: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).email
})
  .then(
    this.setState({
      user: {
        ...this.state.user,
        id: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id,
        firstName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName)
          .firstName,
        lastName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).lastName,
        userName: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).userName,
        password: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).password,
        email: users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).email,
      },
    }),
    this.getPreference(users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id),
    this.getReadings(users.find((user) => user.userName === userName).id)
  )
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

I used b crypt to hash a salted password in my add route I tried to add it but it wont let me
Please any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? I see some things in your JavaScript that look fishy.

Comment: i get a 400 error

Comment: what looks fishy??

Comment: Specifically the destructuring of `userName` and `password` from `req` in the first snippet. You're referencing both `req.body` and `req.query`. Which one do you actually want?

Comment: so I need to take off req.query???

Comment: I'll post what I think is the problem as an answer because a comment is just too small to cover it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is where you are destructuring your `userName` and `password` variables. You currently have this:

```
const {
userName = req.body.userName,
password = req.body.password,
} = req.query;
```

This is a bit of a mixed metaphor. You should either be assigning the variables individually like this:

```
const userName = req.body.userName;
const password = req.body.password;
```

Or [destructuring](https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects) them like this:

```
const {
    userName,
    password
} = req.query;
```

You don't specify what type of backend you're using, but from the `router.post` on the first line, I assume that you are receiving a post. In that case, I would expect the username and password to be in `req.post`. However, when I [try your original code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t051poLv/), I get the values from `req.query`.

You mentioned that you see a 400 in the browser console, and I see that your server code returns a 400 response when the username or password are invalid. So I think that the problem is your server code is not destructuring the request correctly, the `userName` and `password` variables are empty, and thus the validation fails.

So the correct code would either be:

```
const userName = req.body.userName;
const password = req.body.password;
```

Or:

```
const {
    userName,
    password
} = req.body;
```

Comment: I changed it to req.query and I still get a 400 error.. should I change something in handle login and what should it be?

Comment: @WesleyOwen I didn't see anything else in the code that looked suspicious. You should try to get more detail about exactly what is failing. For example, have you checked the body of the response to see if you get either of you error messages back ("invalid username" or "invalid password")? Can you debug or add logging to the backend to see where it fails?

Comment: I did a console log of both the password and password hash and it came up the same string of characters  but said invalid password...